# Gson not constructing inner objects

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to read a json file into java using Gson. So for that I used this line:

```
data = gson.fromJson(json.toString(), MainData.class);
```

I assumed It worked as I can access a field named version inside MainData:

```
System.out.println(data.version);//<-- this works
```

But as soon as I try to retrieve data from the inner objects I get a nullPointerException:

```
System.out.println(data.elemental.Water.a);//<-- this doens't work
```

I looked at a lot of questions that looked like they were the same. But from what I could tell I was doing excactly the same. So my guess is that there is a syntax error somewhere but I just cannot find it. Wich is not that unthinkable as this is my first try to work with json and gson.

Here is my json file:

```
{
"version": "1.1.0",
"values": {
"game": {

},
"elemental": {
  "Air": {

  },
  "Void": {

  },
  "Earth": {

  },
  "Water": {
      "a": "10"
  },
  "Fire": {
    "tickTime": "10"

  }
}
}
}
```

And here my java file:
By the way I also noticed that not all of the constructors are called.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.com.google.gson.Gson;

public class JSONReader {

private static MainData data;

protected static final void readFile() throws IOException{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(Elementals.DataBase, "advanced.json"))));
    StringBuffer json = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        json.append(line);
    }
    System.out.println(json.toString());
    reader.close();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    data = gson.fromJson(json.toString(), MainData.class);

    System.out.println(data.version);//works
    System.out.println(data.elemental.Water.a);//doesn't work
    System.out.println(data.elemental.Fire.tickTime);//doesn't work
}

private class MainData{
    MainData(){//is called
        System.out.println("main");
    }
    private String version;
    private GameData values;
    private ElementalData elemental;

    public class GameData{
        GameData(){//is not called
            System.out.println("gamedata");
        }
    }

    private class ElementalData{
        ElementalData(){//is not called
            System.out.println("elemental");
        }
        private AirData Air;
        private EarthData Earth;
        private WaterData Water;;
        private FireData Fire;
        private VoidData Void;

        private class AirData{

        }

        private class EarthData{

        }

        private class WaterData{
            WaterData(){//is not called
                System.out.println("Water");
            }
            private int a;
        }

        private class FireData{
            private int tickTime;
        }

        private class VoidData{

        }
    }
}
}
```

I hope this was informative enough and I'm looking forward to an answer.

Comment: What if you make those static inner classes?

Comment: There were static first that didn't work either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSON, your `elemental` is nested directly within `values`, not within the root object. Your POJOs need to reflect that. Your class should be like this

```
public class GameData {
    GameData() {// is not called
        System.out.println("gamedata");
    }
    private ElementalData elemental; // instead of in MainData
}
```

and then

```
System.out.println(data.values.elemental.Water.a);
```

Comment: Oh god that was a good act of stupidity on my side. Thank you a lot for the answer.

Comment: @Roan Formatting the JSON with a tool like http://www.jsonlint.com might help see these kinds of errors. I also recommend that you un-nest your classes, not for technical reasons, just readability.